# Import two or more column data from a csv file (comma delimited) and skip the first row using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Assume the following sheet in a csv file as shown in the following image:

[image]

I want to import each column data as list and skip the first row using c# in visual studio.
I need also to know how to browse only the csv file and load it using c#.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This Nuget package will help you parse CSV files: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/ Here is an example: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-class-records

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel on CSV file reading. Install `CsvHelper` via NuGet and then follow the instructions here for how to use: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started
This will save you the trouble of worrying about escaping commas, skipping the header row, handling very large files and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can think of csv files as txt files. The data in csv is saved in the following format(use comma as separator).

```
Name,ID,Salary
AA,102,0
AB,103,0
AC,104,0
```

So you can read data like reading .txt file. As to "browse only the csv file", you can set a filter for `OpenFileDialog`.

Here is a simple demo.

```
List<string> name = new List<string>();
List<string> id = new List<string>();
List<string> salary = new List<string>();

private void btOpenCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Title = "Open CSV";
    ofd.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    ofd.InitialDirectory = "d:\\";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        bool isfirstrow = true; // check if the first row
        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.  
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (isfirstrow)
            {
                isfirstrow = false;
                continue;
            }
            name.Add(line.Split(',')[0]);
            id.Add(line.Split(',')[1]);
            salary.Add(line.Split(',')[2]);
        }
    }
}
```